# Input field string or number detection

Tags: javascript

My code isn’t working, I’d like letters to turn green and numbers to turn red...

```
const inpout = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (const type of inpout) {
  type.addEventListener('input', function() {
    const res = parseInt(this.value);
    if (typeof res === 'number') {
      this.style.color = ('red');
    } else if (isNaN(res)) {
      this.style.color = ('green');
    } else {
      this.style.color = ('green');

    }
  });
```

Comment: what about a alphanumeric value in the input ? eg ABC123XYZ

Comment: @joyBlanks this should be a string I guess

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp this.style.color = String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParseInt will parse a alphanumeric value to a number if it starts with a number, Just add a `+` infront of the value and it will be either NaN or a number

```js
const input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (const type of input) {
  type.addEventListener('input', function() {
    const res = +this.value;
    if (isNaN(res)) {
      this.style.color = ('green');
    }else if (typeof res === 'number') {
      this.style.color = ('red');
    } else {
      this.style.color = ('green');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input /><input /><input /><input />
```

Comment: Awesome! It works! Thanks for the clear explaination and congrats for your ingenuity!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, although I'm not sure if it is want you want:

working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/1sfmrct8/

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (const element of inputs) {
  element.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    const res = e.target.value[e.target.value.length - 1]
    if (isNumeric(res)) {
      this.style.color = ('red');
    } else {
      this.style.color = ('green');
    }
  })
}


function isNumeric(str) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both numbers and strings inputs, values are always strings.

I think that's why your code isn't working, so another (and maybe simpler) solution would be to check `input.type` instead of `input.value`. Something like this:

```
if (this.type === "number") {
  this.style.color = ('red');
} else {
  this.style.color = ('green');
}
```